# Xcode 11 - Fastlane deliver failed

Tags: xcode, fastlane

I'm using fastlane for uploading binaries to App Store Connect.
I need to build my app using Xcode 11, but I can't upload the app to App Store Connect.
error:

> [12:20:49]: Could not find transporter at
>   /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/. Please make sure you
>   set the correct path to your Xcode installation.

Xcode 11 doesn't include the Transporter application anymore.

How do I upload app using fastlane and xcode 11?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode 11 doesn't include the Transporter application anymore.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/301/

But I found the resource 
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14955 and https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/#/apdA3ae5a8b0?sub=apdA687d545d maybe help you resolve problem.

Update: You can download transporter and install to your machine and config path for it.

UPDATE 2:
I just install fastlane and try push appstore using fastlane. No error occurr. Maybe fastlane team fixed this issue.

Comment: I updated fastlane, but still same issue. Be sure that you use xcode 11 beta while you are running fastlane (xcode_select("/Applications/Xcode-beta.app"))

Comment: @phnmnn I added xcode_select and build. No error occur. Please try download transporter and configure.

Comment: I can't download. I'm going to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/resources/download/Transporter__OSX/bin/ (from Transporter User Guide) but it redirect me to: https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/

Comment: @phnmnn after login you can download it.

Comment: I did login... it just redirect me to appstoreconnect.apple.com

Comment: I just download and up to drive https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DALWVoDC30o5omVUDsrbeRBrVjpvYNv9

Comment: Same as me. What is version of fastlane. And what is result after install transport and config

Comment: Updating of fastlane fixed the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: export FASTLANE_ITUNES_TRANSPORTER_PATH=/usr/local/itms

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. update fastlane
2. copy application loader in Xcode10 to Xcode11(find
   application loader in Xcode package content)
   [image]